# Are Sarah or any of the other clones looking for the woman they were cloned from?

Tags: orphan-black

The Orphan Black Wiki says that it is "Still unclear who the original is".

Have Sarah (or Allison or Cosima) sought her out?  If not, is there any evidence that any of them are even curious about who the original is?

Comment: Maybe there *is* no original - could be they were made from scratch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If that wiki still says that, it's out of date.

The search for the original was a major plot point during the third season and the surprising identity of the original was revealed in the last couple of episodes of that season.

> The original turns out to be Shioban's mother, Kendall Malone. She is the single source for both the Leda and the Castor line of clones, since she is a human [chimera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimera_%28genetics%29), both male and female.

Comment: More like the question's out of date, seeing as I asked it about a year ago :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this forms a significant part of the season 2 and 3 plot (enough that it is difficult to go into much detail without a lot of spoilers).

In episode 5 of season 2, Leekie

> tells Cosima that the original genome was lost in a fire

which they were looking for, because it is critical in

> curing Cosima, and then later in season 3, the Castor clones.

The actual identity of the original

> (actually, originals, male and female siblings, one for Leda and one for Castor)

has not been revealed, but it seems likely that this may form a part of the (at time of writing, still being broadcast) season 3 plot.

In general, there is a lot of investigation into the background of the cloning project later in the second season, and so far in the third season.

Comment: Update: The identity was revealed, before the end of Season 3.